# Angular 4 HTTP Jasmine Unit Testing

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm a noob at unit testing, I've been trying to create a mock unit test for a HTTP call to an end point.

My Service:

```
this.http.get('endPoint',options).subscribe((res: Response) => { 
  let result = res.json();
  let obj = new ForgotPasswordResponse(res..........);
  return obj;
})
```

My Unit Test

```
 it('should get response from server', (done) => {
    let responseObj:ForgotPasswordResponse = {
        messageEN: 'dsadsada',
        messageFR: 'dsada',
        headerEN: 'dsada',
        headerFR: 'dsada',
        pageTarget: 'dsada',
        args: 'dsa',
        systemLogs: 'dsada',
        msgCode: 'dsa',
        type: 'dsa'
    }

    let signinid = '1234';
    let lang = 'EN';

    backend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
        let options = new ResponseOptions({ body: responseObj });
        connection.mockRespond(new Response(options));

        expect(connection.request.url).toEqual('./api/v1/forgot/1234/EN');
        expect(connection.request.method).toEqual(RequestMethod.Get);
    });

    subject.initPwdResetFlow(signinid, lang).subscribe((response) => {
        expect(response).toEqual(responseObj);
        done();
    });
});
```

My response object is of type `ForgotPasswordResponse`, with the appropriate props. However, when I run the test, I get a failure -- it only says Type Error thrown.

Answer (score 0):

To mock your HTTP connection, you have to inject the XHRBackend as follows:

#### my-service.spec.ts

```
import { HttpModule, XHRBackend, Response, ResponseOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { MyService } from './my-service';
(...)
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpModule
      ],
      providers: [
        MyService,
        {provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend}
      ]
    });
  });

it('should get a response', (done) => {
  inject([XHRBackend, MyService], (mockBackend: MockBackend, service: MyService) => {
      const body = {content: 'blabla'};
      const status = 200;
      mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
        connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({body, status})));
      });
      service.get().subscribe(response => {
        expect(response).not.toBeNull();
        done();
      });
    })();
});
```